# google app engine datastore django-nonrel Invalid model identifier on loading fixture

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, django-nonrel, django-fixtures

I'm trying to implement django-nonrel on google app engine using datastore as database but i'm getting error on loading fixtures on local development server

```
DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture gae_django/recipe/fixtures/initial_data.json': Invalid model identifier: 'recipe.Recipes'
```

here's my folder structure

```
 ├──gae_django  
    ├── autoload
    ├── dbindexer
    ├── django
    ├── djangoappengine
    ├── djangotoolbox
    ├── functional_test
    ├── recipe
    │   ├── fixtures
    │   └   └──initial_data.json
    │   └── templates
    │   └── models.py
    │   └── tests.py
    └── cooks
        └── __pycache__
```

initial_data.json

```
[
{
    "model": "recipe.Recipes",
    "fields": {
        "title": "Roasted Beef"
    }
}
]
```

models.py

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb
class Recipes(ndb.Model):
   title = ndb.StringProperty()
   desc = ndb.StringProperty()
```

i tried to run

```
python manage.py test recipe 
python manage.py loaddata recipe/fixtures/initial_data.json
```

both giving the same error

Comment: try recipe.models.Recipes

Comment: @RyanB nope, didn't work but i guess im just confused because apparently using `code` from django.db import models
class Recipes(models.Model) works and the transition between gae and django is already handled by djangoappengine and i can just code the django way